# Почему не закрывается ресурс?

Tags: java, try-catch, filechanel

Eclipse пишет, что:

> Resource leak: 'unassigned Closeable value' is never closed

Я же объявил его как ресурс:

```
private static void copyFile(FileChannel sourceFileChannel, File in) throws IOException {

    try(FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(in).getChannel()) {
        sourceFileChannel.transferTo(0, sourceFileChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileChannel` объявили, а кто будет закрывать `new FileOutputStream(in)` ? Вы бы лучше стрим сделали как ресурс, он тогда и `channel` сам закроет

Comment: @RomanDanilov да, спасибо